# Google Assistant Actions: providing a link to the whole response body

Tags: actions-on-google

Often when we ask a query in Google Assistant, it has a feature where by tapping anywhere on the response (say a card) body, it opens a new link window.

However, when I look at the Google Actions SDK docs, the only feature available, is to place a link button at the bottom of the (say, card) response to open the URL in a new window.

Is there a way in which the above mentioned feature can be made available in a custom action? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A [Browsing Carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel) might be the object that you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm. but the specs has no way of specifying an external url (to which it should go on tapping). Besides, the doc states that there must be two items in a carousel. In fact, if you try almost any query in Google Assistant (say, "what is the capital of ...") and if the response is like a card, tapping on it takes you to a URL